# Php replace character just after and before matched string

Tags: php

I have a string like this.

```
3:1,1:2,2:3
```

What I want is to replace a string based on start and end string.
Lets say I want to replace 2 from this part 1:2,
So here my starting string is 1: and end string is ,

The important thing is that I know only the starting and ending string not the replacement one.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code that isn't working to show?

Comment: I have tried almost all php string functions even tried with explode. Actually let me update my question a part is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
preg_replace("/1:2/","1:3",$string);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `str_replace($search, $replace, $string)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$string = '3:1,1:2,2:3';
$string = str_replace('1:2', '1:whateverToReplaceWith', $string);
echo $string;
```

Which will output `3:1,1:whateverToReplaceWith,2:3`

See it here https://3v4l.org/ZmSo4

Or, now you've edited your question and don't know the in between number, `preg_replace`:

```
<?php

    $string = '3:1,1:2,2:3';
    $string = preg_replace('#1:(\d*),#', 'whateverToReplaceWith', $string);
    echo $string;
```

See it here https://3v4l.org/T8FlV

Comment: Sorry, I missed a part in the question just edited my question. This solution won't work for the case.